# ng build dist folder not rendering site

Tags: angular

I'm having issues making my angular2 app work on an ftp server. This is my first time adding angular2 site to ftp server. I ran ng build in the project folder and put the dist folder on the ftp server, but all I get is the message Loading... from index.html Loading... Is there another step after running ng build that I'm missing. I'm also getting the following errors in console[image]

The files it says are missing are in the dist folder so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error. I've been stuck on this for a couple days now so any help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed these issues with the command

```
ng build --base-href="./"
```

and in the angular.json file, must set the property outputPath with only dist.

Here an example: https://javadesde0.com/deploy-subida-de-una-aplicacion-de-angular-a-github-pages-de-forma-totalmente-gratuita/  by David Bernal

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the server to serve from the index file.

> So you would like to deploy your production build to an Apache2
>   server? You will notice then that
>
> reloading pages, besides root, and deep linking will cause 404 errors
>   (unless you are using the HashLocation strategy). The reason is that
>   all Angular2 routes should be served via the index.html file.
>
> This can be achieved by adding a .htaccess file (in the same directory
>   where the index.html resides) with the following contents.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Check [this](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) for more information.